# Caesar Cypher Javascript (from The Odin Project)

Tags: javascript

I am still learning JS and wanted to do this exercise without copying but now I am stuck...I know there are many other things to correct, but for now....I don't know why this function won't let the empty spaces be?

**The function takes a string to be encoded and a shift factor and then returns the encoded string:

caesar('A', 1) // simply shifts the letter by 1: returns 'B'
the cipher should retain capitalization:

caesar('Hey', 5) // returns 'Mjd;
should not shift punctuation:

caesar('Hello, World!', 5) //returns 'Mjqqt, Btwqi!'

```
    const caesar = function (word, x) {
      const alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split("")
      const alphaUp = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toUpperCase().split("")
      const newString = []
      for (const l in word) {
        console.log(word[l])
        console.log(typeof word[l])
        if (word[l] === word[l].toUpperCase()) {
          const index2 = alphaUp.findIndex(b => b == word[l])
          newString.push(alphaUp[index2 + x])
        }
        else if (word[l] === " ") {
          newString.push(word[l])
        }
        else if (word[l] === word[l].toLowerCase()) {
          const index = alpha.findIndex(a => a == word[l])
          newString.push(alpha[index + x])
        }


      }
      console.log(newString.join(""))
    }
    caesar("Hello world!", 5)
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, could you add to your question the expected result ?

Comment: @MartinPaucot done, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the case where you reach the space `" "` in your for loop the first check is

`if (word[l] === word[l].toUpperCase())`

Running .toUppercase() on `" "` returns `" "` so you are running your logic for upperCase letters and never reach the check if it is a space `else if`. Changing the logic order to this works as you intend

```
if (word[l] === " ") {
  newString.push(word[l])
}
else if (word[l] === word[l].toUpperCase()) {
  const index2 = alphaUp.findIndex(b => b == word[l])
  newString.push(alphaUp[index2 + x])
} // rest of the code after
```

Comment: OH, yes, of course, I tried it and it worked! Thanks!